# Does LinkedHashMap returns linked Set?

Tags: java

Method `keySet()`.
Examples works fine, but I not sure if I'm right.

Comment: what method are you talking about?

Comment: @blackliteon, please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` inherets `keySet()` from `HashMap`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#methods_inherited_from_class_java.util.HashMap

`keySet()` returns an object of class `Set`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the JDK1.5 source, it seems that the keyset returned from `LinkedHashMap` defines an iterator whose ordering is consistent with that of the map.

However, since this isn't documented anywhere, I'd treat the behaviour as an implementation detail, and wouldn't rely on it in my code.